# Outputting an equation in C

Tags: c

I'm writing a small program in C that will output a total percentage of CPU usage over a 1 second period. I've got it working for the most part, it does calculate the proper numbers but the final calculation where it divides workOver by totalOver * 100 it always outputs 0. I'm not sure why. Any help would be great. Code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glibtop.h>
#include <glibtop/cpu.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>

unsigned long cpu1Total, cpu1User, cpu1Nice, cpu1Sys, cpu1Work;
unsigned long cpu2Total, cpu2User, cpu2Nice, cpu2Sys, cpu2Work;
unsigned long workOver, totalOver, cpuTotal;

int main(){

    glibtop_init();

    glibtop_cpu cpu;
    glibtop_get_cpu (&cpu);

    cpu1Total = cpu.total;
    cpu1User = cpu.user;
    cpu1Nice = cpu.nice;
    cpu1Sys = cpu.sys;

    cpu1Work = cpu1User + cpu1Nice + cpu1Sys;

    usleep ( 1000000 ) ;

    glibtop_get_cpu (&cpu);

    cpu2Total = cpu.total;
    cpu2User = cpu.user;
    cpu2Nice = cpu.nice;
    cpu2Sys = cpu.sys;

    cpu2Work = cpu2User + cpu2Nice + cpu2Sys;

    workOver = cpu2Work - cpu1Work;
    totalOver = cpu2Total - cpu1Total;

    cpuTotal = workOver / totalOver * 100;

    printf("Cpu Idle : %ld \n", cpuTotal);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: integer division...cast to float first...

Comment: Of course, what an idiot! :P

Comment: If it doesn't overflow, `workOver * 100 / totalOver` avoids the truncation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables in your division are declared as integers.  The problem is if you divide two integers, you will not get a fractional value.  This means if the denominator is > than the numerator, the result will be 0.

Integer division does not automatically produce a floating point result.

To fix this, you can redeclare at least one of your variables in the formula as a float, or even cast them in the calculation.

Comment: Nah, you're fine.  These things are easy to forget and it's natural to assume the highest precision for an operation possible.

Comment: @Steve It's actually good to think (and say) "I'm an idiot" ... shame is a powerful emotion, crafted by evolution, that makes us more conscious about the consequences of our actions.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `unsigned long` when you should be using `float` or `double` to do division.  A `long` or any integer value cannot handle decimal points so if you have a number 0 < x < 1, when the decimal is chopped off, you're left with 0.